# does DevExpress XtraReports have an easily accessible notion of "current detail report being printed"?

Tags: devexpress, subreport, xtrareport

I am printing a details subreport that gets printed let's say 5 times on the overall report, for 5 query results. I compute some stuff for it with my code, and so I use BeforePrint event on an XRTable widget that I have in that subreport. So far so good.

What I don't like is that when the BeforePrint executes for that table for the first time and I change its cells' text to something, that this renders on all subsequent instances of this report and table being printed. Now, obviously, since BeforePrint gets called again, I get the opportunity to reset the text to what it should be. So this is not a show stopper.

Yet, this somehow fills wrong, and an invitation to bugs. Is there a way for me to explicitly access "the instance of the table/other widget being printed" rather than "the widget in general, with changes being rendered in all instances that it prints"?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are right.  If the formatting should be based on the earlier created data or summary, formatting rules won't work.  A possible solution to this problem is to implement a special approach when a developer manually browses all printing system bricks and changes their content manually.  You will find some examples on how this can be done at:

[Implementing Page totals](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q279777)

[subtotal on page bottom and on next page on top](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q272286)