# is there a DevExpress XtraReports event that fires after all widgets of a details subreport got printed, like for formatting?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I want to be able to go through all instances of a printed details subreport and do some formatting of records, in part by computing stuff for one record based on another one already printed. The code that prints reports is a bit of a mess, so I think this particular issue is easiest to handle by a kind of postprocessing of a printed report rather than by changing the underlying data binding etc code.

Well, frankly, I am unable to find a way even to get to the point where I could format text records in a single XRTable (XRTable.AfterPrint event does not work for me here) let alone format one XRTable based on values output in another one.

Any suggestions? Is this a FAQ with a standard answer or a FAQ with "we are tired of telling people it cannot be done" answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event :(.  A possible solution I've posted by answering

[does DevExpress XtraReports have an easily accessible notion of “current detail report being printed”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651109/does-devexpress-xtrareports-have-an-easily-accessible-notion-of-current-detail-r/5668194#5668194)

question.